# Epos_hardware write output error when running example.launch

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am working with EPOS2 70/10 and a maxon EC motor whose shaft is already attached to load. I am using epos_hardware indigo-devel branch package in UBuntu 14.04 x86 4.4.0-38-generic and ROS indigo. I am trying to use the epos_hardware package in order to control velocity on motor. After dealing with the usb rights problems (further info solved in other questions), now I am able to detect the motor using list_devices node. I just adapted the example's launch, urdf and yaml files in order to match my motor settings.

The problem is than when running the launch file (which loads motor settings and enables velocity and position controller) loads the controllers (joint_state and velocity_controller), starts them (look at info message below), the green led is running continously (which means that is properly working) and then the following message appears:

```
[INFO] [WallTime: 1475677663.913912] Started controllers: joint_state_controller1, velocity_controller1

Write processed successfully, but number of bytes written is 0: Operation now in progress
Write processed successfully, but number of bytes written is 0: Operation now in progress
Write processed successfully, but number of bytes written is 0: Operation now in progress
```

When trying to set a velocity (rostopic pub /velocity_controller/command std_msgs/Float64 '##'; #:Number between my motor velocity range) the /diagnosis topic shows me this:

```
---
header: 
  seq: 501
  stamp: 
    secs: 1475678169
    nsecs: 978535919
  frame_id: ''
status: 
  - 
    level: 0
    name: epos_hardware: my_joint_actuator1: Motor
    message: Enabled
    hardware_id: 662080006194
    values: 
      - 
        key: Actuator Name
        value: test_joint_actuator1
          - 
            key: Enabled
            value: True
          - 
            key: Fault
            value: False
          - 
        key: Voltage Enabled
        value: True
      - 
        key: Quickstop
        value: True
      - 
        key: Warning
        value: False
  - 
    level: 1
    name: epos_hardware: my_joint_actuator1: Motor Output
    message: Nominal Current Exceeded (Current: 10.506000 A)
    hardware_id: 662080006194
    values: 
      - 
        key: Commanded Velocity
        value: 250 rpm
      - 
        key: Operation Mode
        value: Profile Velocity Mode
      - 
        key: Nominal Current
        value: 9.8399999999999999 A
      - 
        key: Max Current
        value: 10.5 A
      - 
        key: Position
        value: 0 rotations
      - 
        key: Velocity
        value: 0 rpm
      - 
        key: Torque
        value: 10.506 Nm
      - 
        key: Current
        value: 10.506 A
      - 
        key: Target Reached
        value: True
      - 
        key: Current Limit Active
        value: False
```

So, velocity and position tells me that the shaft is not moving but torque is supposedly not zero (no access to see shaft as is already installed on the machine) and current is even sometimes exceeding my nominal values. From this I take that the problem may be that:

- The load is too much for the motor
  torque to even move.
- There might be a problem with the
  epos_library function when accessing
  to the parameters or a problem with
  communication.

  - Kernel compatibility problem
- Combination of both or other random
  issue (because former team members
  were able to run the motor free
  shaft with this package).

From what I have read, the command library functions return 0 in case that they are unsuccessful so this is the main reason why I am focusing the problem of not moving the load on this error instead of the overload case. Yet, I do not know any way to check which function is returning such an output (should be related with epos_hardware_node).

I would thank you if any of you can make any guess on which may be the problem or how to solve it. Also if there is any other reliable package to control epos2 in ROS. If any further detail is needed I will update the information given.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245047/epos_hardware-write-output-error-when-running-example.launch/) by [Bogdar_](https://answers.ros.org/users/25988/bogdar_/) on ROS Answers with karma: 136 on 2016-10-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

At this point I kept working with the package. I wanted to manage multiple EPOS in a CAN net by managing them through accessing to one of them via USB. The following message was kept being printed periodically as I mentioned in my question:

```
Write processed successfully, but number of bytes written is 0: Operation now in progress
Write processed successfully, but number of bytes written is 0: Operation now in progress
Write processed successfully, but number of bytes written is 0: Operation now in progress
```

I could launch the controller but I lost control of the EPOS after sometime by not know reason. I did not know if the problem was due to the limited handling package capability of EPOS or if I was not defining rigth my URDF or if there was some kind of bug in the implementation of the controllers of the hardware abstraction of ros_control (not so much reliable documentation explaining in detail its behavior).

The level of documentation of this package is quite poor from my point of view. A lot of explanations on the ROS Code API is missing and it gets really messy to look debug sometimes. It is a great idea but it gives the sensation that the work was left have done (as realease version was published as 0.0.3).

The USB connection works but when trying to make it work in the configuration I was testing the USB falls making it impossible to communicate with the EPOS unless the code is relaunch. Then you have to pray for the system to be able to clear errors on the first try.

I debugged my code, my URDF and I was not understanding the reasons behind this. Also tried in Windows LabView 2015 and the system did not lost control, the problem of the implementation of this package is that depends on dll libraries which are not supported in Linux based OS so I could not (yet) working with the linux library implementation of epos control.

It seems that the USB communication is not suitable or robust enough so I would recommend to change to RS232 (google the differences on how the communication is done in each case). At least now it looks that I am not experiencing the USB connection fall but I will update with my results in future.

Hope I can save you some time that **this problem has taken from me.**

---

Originally posted by [Bogdar_](https://answers.ros.org/users/25988/bogdar_/) with karma: 136 on 2017-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1